# What is the correct way to declare and initialize Page classes in UI Automation?

Tags: oop, ui-automation

I'm wondering if I'm handling my Page Classes correctly. Currently - when declaring a class for a page on a Mobile App - I declare the identifiers for UI elements I'll be working with in the Constructor - but then keep the calls for actually finding the UI elements inside separate WaitForLoad() methods.

Is that correct?

On one hand it feels inefficient for my Test methods to be doing something like this every time:

AssistPage ap = new AssistPage();
if (!ap.WaitForLoad()) return;

But on the other hand... I don't know how to handle it if something fails to load while running code in the Constructor. A WaitForLoad() method can catch the exception, log an error and return false. But Constructor just returns the page itself - how would the code following it really know if page in question fully loaded?